# MySQL: Get top 30 rows with the highest number of columns set

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with the following schema:

```
user_id | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M
------------------------------------------------------------
3829    | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1
```

The colums `A-M` have boolean values, which are obviously 0 or 1.

Is there a way, aside from looping through all the columns, to:

- get the number of columns that are set to `1` for a specific user, **as well as**
- get the top 30 (or n) users who have **the most** columns set to `1`?

I have a fair amount of experience with `php` and `MySQL` but a query like this is puzzling me.

I'm envisioning something of this sort:

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE count(*) > 1 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 30";
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Why do you have this design, as opposed to a more normalised one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can also use plus(+) as sum

```
SELECT A + B + C + D + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M AS total,user_id
FROM my_table
ORDER BY total
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished using adding the booleans and a `FROM` [sub-query select statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html).

- As bool is stored as a bit you can use sum to get a running total for each row.
- With this data then get to top n results with the highest value.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M AS Total
    FROM Table1
)
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Or if you do not want to use a sub-query <strike>you will have to use a group by due to the use of the aggregate SUM function.</strike>

**UPDATE**: As I am not using the SUM function any more the group by in the second function is not needed so I have removed that too.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *, A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M AS Total
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Yes i mixed my SQL syntax its limit not top ... I have fixed it.

Comment: @Sej it would also seam that MySql does not like to sum booleans so I have updated the answers with the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple you just have to sort the data in decreasing order of the sum of all the other numeric column and fetch the first 30. That will give you the Top 30. This is tricky, as there is no aggregation to be done, so using `sum` function here is not right. So your query is supposed to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY (A + B + C + D + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M) DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/036c25/25)**